# Luraproject returning 404 for configured endpoints

Tags: go, api-gateway, gateway, krakend

I am using a golang project called [lura](https://github.com/luraproject/lura) as gateway for my golang microservices. I have configured all endpoints which are supposed to be accessed via the gateway in the configs properly. But there are few endpoints which end up getting a 404 from the gateway and sometimes it goes through. I am bit confused why that would work partially.

I did face a similar issue before, but I bumped up the version to a newer one and it worked. Now I did the same thing but still happens a lot of times.